# Disable Submit button unless a form option has picked

Tags: html, forms, dropdown

I've checked a few pages online on how to disable a submit button of a dropdown box unless an option has been selected. But can't find one that works for me.
Any help on how to do that would be great!

Edit: I don't want `<option value="not_valid">-- select an option --</option>` to be considered as an option

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
  <select name="attacks" id="attacks">
    <option value="not_valid">-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="attack1">1</option>
    <option value="attack2">2</option>
    <option value="attack3">3</option>
    <option value="attack4">4</option>
    <option value="attack5">5</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="battle" onclick="game()" value="Battle">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with Javascript or jQuery? Because without these two, you cannot add behavior to a page element.

Comment: Yes I have, have you got any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

use onChange event

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="action_page.php">
      <select name="attacks" id="attacks" onchange="selectChanged()">
        <option value="not_valid">-- select an option --</option>
        <option value="attack1">1</option>
        <option value="attack2">2</option>
        <option value="attack3">3</option>
        <option value="attack4">4</option>
        <option value="attack5">5</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="battle" onclick="game()"  value="Battle">
    </form>
  <script>
 function selectChanged(){
        attacks = document.getElementById("attacks");
        if(attacks.value =="not_valid"){//or whatever th unwanted value is
            document.getElementById("battle").disabled = true;
        } else{
            document.getElementById("battle").disabled = false; 
        }
    }          
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, even when I use just the HTML I provided above and your JS on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Just now I tried it on JSFiddle and it didn't work as you said, but it definitely does if you try it by manually creating html file with the code I just edited which is the same except html, head, body tags.